# FullCalendar Does NOT Support "Tap/Touch" Select/Create Event? without holding?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, touch

from my understanding, the only way to select a timeslot on the calendar from a touch device is to tap and hold, I'm looking for a way to handle tap in the same way the calendar grid handles on click. I do not see a way to do this in the documentation.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch

Comment: If it's not documented then it's unlikely to exist. I'm not aware of anything else. The reason is probably because you can actually drag to select a larger time slot, and also tapping is probably considered like a "click" on the day, which triggers a different callback event.

Comment: @ADyson Fair enough, I suspected as much, but I'm not super familiar with FullCalendar so wanted to double-check if I was missing something simple, thanks for the answer, I really appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was provided by [ADyson in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451847/fullcalendar-does-not-support-tap-touch-select-create-event-without-holding/73463156#comment129720383_73451847):

> If it's not documented then it's unlikely to exist. I'm not aware of
> anything else. The reason is probably because you can actually drag to
> select a larger time slot, and also tapping is probably considered
> like a "click" on the day, which triggers a different callback event.

I suspected that this would be the case, but I'm not super familiar with FullCalendar, so I wanted to double-check in case I was missing something.